# How to make multiple listboxes change the value when one of the value in a listbox is clicked in oracle- adf?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have **Master table(M1)** and **detail table(D1)**. The detail table(**D1**) has 2 fields, seq1(foreign key of M1), seq2(foreign key of another table say M2). The **M1** and **D1** table has one to many relationship. The **M2** table has 6 fields say seq2 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5. The below is the table in detail.

**M1** 
**seq1 fieldM1 fieldM2 fildM3**

**M2**
**seq2 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5**

**D1**
**seq1 seq2**

In my page I have a master form(M1) and detail table(D1). onClick of addChild the new detail rows can be added. In the detail table within the page I am showing 5 fields. 3 listBoxes and two readOnly textBoxes. All the data for the details table is getting from the M2 table.

Here are my business scenarios:
on change of any of the listBoxes the remaining 4 fields should be populated automatically by retrieving from the M2 table and the seq2 of D1 should be updated from the M2 table.

Here is my question:
1) Can I do this in a declarative approach?

Is there any better approach to create the ADF businessComponents. Please provide me enough details because I am new to ADF.
For more details please find the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Hey Sarath, did an answer helped ? Don't forget to accept if it did https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this declarative.
You can use list of values attribute in your ViewObject declaration.
LOVs can update several attributes in your detail VO.
Here is a short instruction:
http://atadf.blogspot.com.by/2013/06/how-to-define-list-of-values-for-view.html

Comment: Yes, I am able to use the listBoxes. But my query is how can I change the values on selection of one of the values in listBox using declarative approach?

Comment: In your detail ViewObject you should have two SQL attributes and other 5 shoud be transient (they need only to display additional data from masters). Also you should declare 2 View accsesors for your masters. To declare view accesors you should create 2 sql viewobjects for m1 and m2. After, configure 2 transient attributes to have "List of Values" which will be connected to accessors. Each LOV will update detail's fields (seq1, seq2) automatically from m1 and m2.

Comment: yes, I have created 5 transient attributes for my detail table. Now, I am able to render the details. But, as per my requirement, OnChange of DrugId LOV, the remaining fields should be populated automatically. For this either we can write a query for the onChange listener of the ListBox. Is there any other approach to automatically query?
<br></br>
For eg:
DrugId - a, b, c
DrugDescription - i, ii, iii
ChemName - 1, 2, 3
<br></br>
OnChange of any values in the ListBox the remaining should be populated automatically.
This mapping is already done in the above mentioned m2 tablec

Answer (score 0):

To do so you have to add a valueChangeListener function on the LOV that will trigger the refresh.

e.g:

```
<af:selectOneChoice simple="true" id="userSelectOneChoice"
                            valueChangeListener="#{myScope.mybean.getRefreshData}"
                            autoSubmit="true">
          <f:selectItems value="#{myScope.mybean.myList}"
                         id="userSelectItems"/>
        </af:selectOneChoice>
```

You can calculate the data you want to display in this valueChangeListener as it will be trigger when a specific value is selected :

```
public void getRefreshData(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent){
     String selectedItem= String.valueOf(valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());
     //Refresh my data below
}
```

Once the data is refresh you need to trigger a partial rendering of the table to allow the newly refreshed data to be displayed.

To do so add a partialTriggers="userSelectOneChoice" on the parent element of your table.